# Multiple/Concatenate transactions doctrine - Symfony

Tags: symfony, transactions, doctrine

I want to make two consecutives transactions with Doctrine in Symfony 3.
The first transaction it's ok but the second it seem's that is working because the $insertedRows always get 1 and is not doing the rollback aparently but when is doing the commit it seems is not applying this last insert. If I search the row in the real database is not there.

I leave here an example of what I'm doing.

```
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $db->setAutoCommit(false);

    //the first transaction it's to update a register with another num
    try{
        $num = $this->getNum($params);
        if(!($num > 0)){ $db->rollBack();}

        $updatedRows = $this->updateNum($params);
        if($updatedRows === 0){ $db->rollBack();}

        $db->commit();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $db->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
    //until here is ok. I can see the changes in the database


    //this second transatcion I don't know why is not working.
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $db->setAutoCommit(false);
    try{
        $insertedRows = $this->insertNewRegister($params);
        if($insertedRows === 0){ $db->rollBack();}
        //the insertedRows is equal to 1 if I do a dump here, so it seems is inserting this new row 
        //but after the commit if I check this new row in the database is not there

        $db->commit();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $db->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? PErhaps anyone can show me an example of two consecutive transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve problem with removing second call

```
$db->beginTransaction();
```

Problem with your second call of

```
$db->beginTransaction();
```

is when you setup `setAutoCommit(false)` after         `$db->commit();` new transaction is automatically open, so you don't need to open new transaction.

You can read documentation [doctrine-project](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.7/reference/transactions.html#auto-commit-mode).